# Google protobuf repeated fields with C++

Tags: c++, c++14, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a requirement to build the following `Metadata` message using serialized key value pairs in C++.

```proto
message MetadataValue {
  string key = 1;
  google.protobuf.Value value = 2;
}

message Metadata {
  repeated MetadataValue metadata = 1;
}
```

So I can have the values for `MetadataValue` from the following for statement in C++.

```cpp
Metadata metadata; 
  if (buffer.has_value()) {
    auto pairs = buffer.value()->pairs();
    for (auto &p : pairs) {
      MetadataValue* metadataValue = metadata.add_metadata();
      metadataValue->set_key(std::string(p.first));
      // I don't know how to set the value for google.protobuf.Value 
    }
  }
```

My question is whether my approach is correct ? Are there better alternatives and how to set the google.protobuf.Value in that above scenario ? A simple code snippet with the answer is much appreciated.

Comment: You can check the protoc generated source files to find proper APIs

Comment: What's the type of buffer

Comment: I know but here it's different. I usually do *metadataValue.mutable_value() = value but here since it's repeated and inside that for loop I can't do that. I tried metadataValue->mutable_value() and it says expression is not assignable.

Comment: type of buffer is a complicated one. it's a specified type defined in a proxy. pairs return key and values and I think that's enough for us to deal with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code works, I just checked the generated APIs by protoc.

If the `typeof(p.second)` is not a `google::protobuf::Value`, you need to add conversion like

```cpp
auto v = google::protobuf::Value();
v.set_number_value(p.second);
// or p.second is string
// v.set_string_value(p.second);
```

```cpp
Metadata metadata; 
  if (buffer.has_value()) {
    auto pairs = buffer.value()->pairs();
    for (auto &p : pairs) {
      MetadataValue* metadataValue = metadata.add_metadata();
      metadataValue->set_key(std::string(p.first));
      *metadataValue->mutable_value() = p.second;
      // I don't know how to set the value for google.protobuf.Value 
    }
  }
```

And I am using `protoc` version 3

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
message MetadataValue {
  string key = 1;
  google.protobuf.Value value = 2;
}

message Metadata {
  repeated MetadataValue metadata = 1;
}
```

Comment: ` auto v = google::protobuf::Value();  
    v.set_string_value(p.second);` does not work for me. It says error: no matching member function for call to 'set_string_value'

Comment: Are you using `syntax = "proto3";`? Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I think the issue is with the way that proxy sends me the buffer. They converts everything to basic strings.

Comment: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__2::basic_string_view<char, std::__2::char_traits<char>>' to 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>') for 1st argument

Comment: And v.set_string_value() expects a std::string. So I guess I have to do a static_cast(Not sure). Maybe some other type of cast ?

Comment: If you can't find such an api, it may be caused by your `protoc` version is too low. I am using `libprotoc 3.6.1`

Comment: Just use this `v.set_string_value(std::string(v.data(), v.size()))` with explicit conversion.

Comment: I think I'll just use the type string for that instead. Because no point of using Value when all the stuff i get in pairs are strings. I need to perform some processing in the remote service to get the original types. I'm writing a filter for envoy proxy in web assembly and they convert protobuf to serialized key value pairs.